# Passing an INT array into a SQL stored procedure

Tags: sql, arrays, sql-server

I'm struggling to find what I thought would be a simple solution.

I have an array of `customerID`'s and I want to pass that into a stored procedure to find the `notificationID`'s of those customers.

For example:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[getCustomerNotificationIDs]
    @customerIDs *array*

    SELECT [NotificationID]
    FROM [dbo].[CustomerNotifications]
    WHERE [CustomerID] IN @customerIDs
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction please?

Comment: Yes I am, and using Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio to access it.

Comment: T-SQL has no support for arrays